# CloudWatch logs insights strcontains not working

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a CloudWatch log group where all the logs are JSON objects that look like

```
{
   "job-name": "bb0e964b-a7f8-41e3-b1fc-8de4306c0b84",
   "event-name": "PERSIST_LAMBDA_INVOKED",
   "log-message": "Persistence lambda invoked for line 238."
}
```

I'm trying to get all messages where `event-name` is `"HUMAN_TASK_FAILED"`

Note that `event-name` is a discovered field.

However, the following query doesn't return any matches

```
fields @timestamp, @message, strcontains(event-name, "HUMAN_TASK_FAILED") as found 
| filter found = 1
```

I've also tried running the query below to debug,

```
fields @timestamp, @message, strcontains(event-name, "HUMAN_TASK_FAILED") as found
```

but the `found` column is always blank (even when `event-name` is `"HUMAN_TASK_FAILED"`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both queries are ok. The problem is related to the field format.

It seems that CloudWatch Logs Insights does not work well with fields containing hyphen ("-"). I have tested changing in the log events event-name by event_name, run the query and it works fine.

[image]